# fast way to get graphic output in c++ eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, graphics

Im currently working on an excercise about lagrange interpolation. I'm on the point where i would like to plot my data. So I thought there must be a quick and easy way to generate a window and draw some points in eclipse. 
Well seams like I thought wrong. I searched on google and I found a shitload of different libarys, all of them either outdated, useless or with a really long installation guide. 
The graphic output is really just to test my interpolation, so I want to spend as less time as possible with it. I remeber that there was a libary for java which was pretty simple. You could just import the libary, make a command to initialise a window, and then draw in it. There was no need for a installation and going from zero to a window with a circle was about three commands. 
Is there really nothing like that for C++? What could I do to keep it as simple and fast (to install) as possible? 
Thanks

Comment: fastest way is probably to write the result to a file and then use your favourite visualisation tool (eg gnuplot) to draw the graph. Btw the question is offtopic for SO

Answer (score 0):

> Is there really nothing like that for C++?

Not really. C++ includes the "standard library" and that's it. The functionality you're looking for is provided by third-party libraries, as you've already found.

Asking for library recommendations is specifically off-topic on StackOverflow, by the way.